# Speaking Entered Text

Tags: ios, speech

I am currently creating an app where I need the app to speak what the user has entered.

Example: if user entered the word `cat` I need the app to say `cat`.

I am using Xcode 5. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you understand it would be kind of like a dictation app.

Comment: Maybe look at: `AVSpeechSynthesizer`, and `AVSpeechUtterance`.

Comment: What have you tried? Searching the documentation for [speech synthesis](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/search/?q=Speech+synthesis) might be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`
the you need an `AVSpeechSynthesizer`:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
```

and can use `AVSpeechUtterance` to speak strings:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"textToSpeak"];
//adjust the speed
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate; 
//set the language
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-us"];
//speak it
[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```